# a for loop not executed in an operating system C

Tags: c, operating-system, microcontroller

I have problems while executing a for loop, I created a static table which contains defined values, then I pass my table as an argument in a function to process. 
basicly my code looks like the following one:

```
#define ID_01 0x0000
#define ID_02 0x0001
#define ID_03 0x0002
#define ID_04 0x0003
#define ID_05 0x0004
#define ID_06 0x0005
#define ID_07 0x0006
#define ID_08 0x0007
#define ID_09 0x0008
/*...
*/
#define ID_LAST 0xFFFF
static char table[]={
ID_01, ID_02 ,ID_03, ID_04, .... , ID_LAST}

void process( char *table){

    int LastId=0; 
    char *Command; 

    for ( Command=table; LastId==0 ; Command++){
        switch(Command) 
        {
            case ID_01: 
                do_stuff01();
                break;
            case ID_02: 
                do_stuff02();
                break; 
            ...

            case ID_LAST: 
                LastId=1;
                break;
            default: 
                 break;
          } 
    }
}
```

I've tried to print some messages to debug but the program does not execute any of the printed even those  before the for and after the loop.

But when I've changed my for loop into :

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
```

all the messages were printed. but I have to process the same way I did in the first place.

PS: this part of code is executed in an operating system task running into a microcontroller and I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you are using `switch (Command)` where `Command` holds address od `table` variable.

Change `switch` to

```
switch (*Command) { //Use value at pointed Command.

}
```

And note, when doing `*Command` you dereference `char` which is 1byte. Your ID's have 2 bytes, therefore you have loss of data.

Change:

```
static char table[] = {ID_01, ID_02 ,ID_03, ID_04, .... , ID_LAST}
```

to short to have 16-bits values

```
static unsigned short table[]={ID_01, ID_02 ,ID_03, ID_04, .... , ID_LAST}
```

Later, modify your `process` function to accept `unsigned short`

```
void process( const unsigned short *table) { //Unsigned short
    int LastId = 0; 
    unsigned short *Command;  //Unsigned short

    for ( Command=table; LastId==0 ; Command++){
        switch(*Command) { //Added star
            //...
        }
    }
    //...
```

---

I would rewrite your `process` code to:

```
void process(const unsigned short *table, size_t tableLen) {
    while (tableLen--) {
        switch (*table) {
            case ID_1: /* Do stuff */ break;
        }
        table++; //Increase pointer to next ID element
    }
}

//Usage then like this:
static unsigned short table[] = {ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, ..., ID_n};
//Put pointer and length of table
process(table, sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[0]));
```

Comment: my loop is being executed but the table++ is not working, the loop is stuck in the first defined value

Comment: What does it mean by *stuck*. Did you debug? Did you cover all possible cases and `default` statement?

Comment: Yes I covered all of them, and used a default value. my program execute  only the first item of "*table" in loop

Answer (score 1):

In generally, it makes struct and map the ID/FUNC like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ID_01 0x0000
#define ID_02 0x0001
/* ... */
#define ID_LAST 0xFFFF

typedef void (*func)();

typedef struct {
  char n;
  func f;
} fmap;

void do_something01() { }
void do_something02() { }
/* ... */

static fmap fmaps[] = {
  {ID_01, do_something01},
  {ID_02, do_something02},
  /* ... */
  {ID_LAST, NULL},
};
```